# Gridster Resize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I am working on gridster.js and I am fairly new to it. I have created following snippet which is supossed to Add,Remove and resize widgets..Add and Remove is working perfectly ,however Resize is not working.

Please Refer to following code. Thank you for your help in advance ..!!

```js
<script>
 var gridster;
 
 $(function(){
 
  gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
           widget_base_dimensions: [100, 55],
           widget_margins: [5, 5],
           helper: 'clone',
           resize: {
               enabled: true,
               
           },
          
         }).data('gridster');
  
   $(document).on( "click", "#addWidgetButton", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       gridster.add_widget.apply(gridster, ['<li class="gridster">new <div class="deleteWidgetDiv">X</div><span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span> </li>', 1, 2]);
          $(document).on( "click", ".deleteWidgetDiv", function() {
              $(this).closest( "li" ).addClass("activ");
              gridster.remove_widget($('.activ'));
          });
```

```css
 .gridster ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: gray;
}
.gridster ul li {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static '../js/jquery.draggable.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static '../js/jquery.coords.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="{% static '../js/jquery.gridster.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static '../js/jquery.gridster.css' %}" type="text/css"></script>

<body>
  <button id="addWidgetButton">Add widget</button>
   <div id="log"></div>
    <div class="gridster">
    <ul>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <div class="deleteWidgetDiv">X</div></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <div class="deleteWidgetDiv">X</div></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
          <div class="deleteWidgetDiv">X</div></li>
          <li data-row="4" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs-w">New   <div                  class="deleteWidgetDiv">X</div></li>
  
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```